# Swapping two sublists in a list

Tags: python, list

Given the following list:

```
my_list=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I want to be able to swap the sub-list `my_list[2:4]` with the sub-list `my_list[7:10]` as quickly and as efficiently as possible, to get the new list:

```
new_list=[0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12]
```

Here's my attempt:

```
def swap(s1, s2, l):

    seg1=l[:s1.start]+l[s2]
    seg2=l[s1.stop : s2.start]
    seg3=l[s1]+l[s2.stop:]

    return seg1+seg2+seg3


print swap(slice(2,4), slice(7,10), [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
```

This does print the desired output, although this way of doing it looks awful to me.

Is there a more easy and elegant way of doing it, that will not create four new lists for every function call? (I plan to call this function a lot)

I don't mind (actually I'd prefer) changing the original list, rather than creating new instance every function call.

Comment: What about  `my_list[2:4] = my_list[7:10]` ?

Comment: This will overwrite `my_list[2:4]`.

Comment: I do not get it because it creates : `[0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`

Comment: In case you would like to keep the old list what about `new_list = my_list[:], new_list[2:4] = new_list[7:10]`

Comment: Swapping the two sub lists using the old fashion way (with a temp) will not work  for sub-lists of different sizes.

Comment: `len(seg1)-1` in your code should be `s1.stop`, no?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Slices can be assigned.

Two variables can be swapped with `a, b = b, a`.

Combine the two above::

```
>>> my_list[7:10], my_list[2:4] = my_list[2:4], my_list[7:10]
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12]
```

---

<sub>Beware that - if slices have different sizes - the **order is important**: If you swap in the opposite order, you end up with a different result, because it will change first the initial items (lower indices), and then the higher index items (but those will be shifted in a different position by the first assignment).</sub>

<sub>Also, slices must not overlap.</sub>

Comment: Great. This looks much better and simple, and it also changes the original - which is preferable.  Thank you.

Comment: yes, you can not swap the list in the opposite order. If using a function, we can judge the boundary of the two ranges first.

Comment: A corner case that fails with this are overlapping ranges... however I'm not sure whether they produce any meaningful result in any case...

Comment: @Bakuriu, I will test for overlapping cases too, thanks.

Comment: Upvoting for the Beware note in smallcase -- explains the behavior that I did not understand before.

Answer (score 6):

You can use normal swapping technique (`x,y = y,x`) here, but only if you perform the swap in the correct order: `x` must be the second (rightmost) slice, while `y` is the first (leftmost) slice.

```
>>> my_list=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> my_list[7:10], my_list[2:4] = my_list[2:4], my_list[7:10]
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12]
```

This works because it will assign to `my_list[7:10]` first, and only then to `my_list[2:4]`.

If you perform this in the reverse order, assigning to `my_list[2:4]`  first will change the location of the items on the right due to the sublists having different lengths, which will give incorrect results.

Performance-wise, this may or may not be faster than your code: it probably depends on the length of the list and the slices. You will have to test it on typical use-cases to see.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to use concatenation and slicing. If you pass the list and then two lists with index pairs then you can just slice apart the list and rearrange the two sublists. Note that `indexA` and `indexB` both work in the some way as regular slicing, the start number is included but the end one is not.

```
def replace(source, indexA, indexB):
    newList = source[:indexA[0]] + source[indexB[0]:indexB[1]]
    newList += source[indexA[1]:indexB[0]] + source[indexA[0]:indexA[1]]
    newList += source[indexB[1]:]
    return newList

myList = replace(myList, [2,4], [7,10])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly obvious (or efficient) but it works. I was curious to see if the slice object could be further utilised.

```
import itertools

def replace(s1, s2, l):
    lslice = [slice(0,s1.start), s2, slice(s1.stop, s2.start), s1, slice(s2.stop,len(l))]
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([l[x] for x in lslice]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an other way to do it:

```
import itertools
my_list=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
my_list2 = []
my_list2.extend((my_list[0:2],my_list[7:10],my_list[4:7],my_list[2:4],my_list[10:]))
new_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list2)
```

`new_list` print output:

```
[0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much better to use list index as parameters.

If you'd like to redefine your replace fuction like this:

```
my_list=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

def slice_replace(src_list, l_start, l_end, r_start, r_end):
    if l_end <= r_start:
        return src_list[:l_start] + src_list[r_start:r_end] + src_list[l_end:r_start] + src_list[l_start:l_end] + src_list[r_end:]
    else:
        return slice_replace(src_list, r_start, r_end, l_start, l_end)

print my_list
new_list = slice_replace(my_list, 2, 4, 7, 10)
print new_list

new_list = slice_replace(my_list, 7, 10, 2, 4)
print new_list
```

I have fixed it.

Comment: This can't possibly work correctly. It only performs three slices, but there are 5 segments that need to be combined in total (the two given slices, and the parts of the list before/between/after them).

Comment: @interjay Why 5 segments? I'm afraid I didn't see the point .

Comment: Try running your code and see if it gives the required result.

Comment: The asker wants to swap the sublists with each other, not just overwriting one with the other.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Got it.